# Http failure response for http://localhost:8000/api/... 500 Internal Server Error in angular 5

Tags: angular, angular5, angular6

[image: Its my component where I am posting data[![Its my service to post the data. and . What's my mistake]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h2fY1.png)

This API is working fine as I tested using postman. Please help me

Comment: where is the `httpOptions`?

Comment: Does the webserver you are using provide error logs? Answer as to exact cause may be in there, but I'm not seeing any  definition for the `httpOptions` either...

Comment: Always share your code in text format and share all the variables and functions' full definition which are in your code snippet

Answer (score 0):

Use `this.httpOptions()` instead `httpOptions`, you have to define `this.httpOptions()` function somewhere and import options from there,

else try this code, this is suffice for now:

```
postMember(Member): Observable<any> {
  return this.http.post('http://localhost:8000/api/members/store', JSON.stringify(Member), {headers: this.getCommonHeaders()})
      .map(res => res.json())
      .catch(err => Observable.throw(err));
}

//function for fetching headers, you can define according to your need over here..
      getCommonHeaders(){
        let headers = new Headers();
        headers.append('Content-Type','application/json');
        return headers;
      }
```

Comment: having the same issue. i think its not issue of http.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whats going on with your code. But same problem I faced on my project work. But I read the documentation and solved it properly. Into your screen shot I saw that you are sending a request where you pass (body value, and headers as httpOptions) everything is okay but please check this two point given below :

1. You are running a localhost api service. so At fast you need to solve the CORS (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing) which should be true from server site otherwise any request will not accept by the browser.
2. Please input the httpOptions credentials as I mention below.(Note I am using a GET request angular 7.2.14)

> ```
>      getcategories():Observable<any> {
>
>          const httpOptions = {
>               headers: new HttpHeaders(
>               { 
>                  'Authorization': 'Your Token',
>                  'Content-Type': 'application/json'
>               })
>           }
>
>         return this.httpclient.get("http://localhost:8000/api/v1/categories/", httpOptions);
>
>       }
> ```

Thank you. Hope for the Best .

Comment: is this ionic app?

Comment: No its not an ionic app its web app. also you can try it for ionic, I hope it will work there too. because both are 'Typescript' .

Answer (score 0):

**Express server**

```js
const express = require("express");    
const app = express();
const cors = require("cors");
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    //Enabling CORS
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET,HEAD,OPTIONS,POST,PUT");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, x-client-key, x-client-token, x-client-secret, Authorization");
    next();
});
app.post("/members",cors(),  (req, res)=>{
    console.log(req.body);
    res.status(200).send({"message" : "data received"});
});
```

Angular side:
In the src folder create json file proxy.conf.json and paste the below code:

```js
{
    "/api/*": {
        "target": "http://localhost:8000",
        "secure": false,
        "logLevel": "debug"
    }
}
```

In the angular.json

in the architect, paste

```js
"architect": {
    "options": {
        "proxyConfig": "src/proxy.conf.json"
    }
}
```

There should be an api with same endpoints on the server side as you create on the angular to receive the data otherwise you will face an error 500.